# Loot modifiers not being applied Minecraft Forge 1.20.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Mobs will not drop items I've added to their loot tables through loot modifiers. I have like sixty loot modifier files but, to keep it simple, let's say my only loot modifier is spider_charm_from_spiders.json. That file looks like:

```
{
  "type": "reinvigoration:add_item",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
      "predicate": {
        "type": "minecraft:spider"
      },
      "entity": "this"
    },
    {
      "condition": "minecraft:killed_by_player"
    }
  ],
  "item": "reinvigoration:spider_charm"
}
```

and is located in src/main/resources/data/reinvigoration/loot_modifiers/spider_charm_from_spiders.json

My global_loot_modifiers.json class located in src/main/resources/data/forge/loot_modifiers/global_loot_modifiers.json looks like this:

```
{
  "replace": false,
  "entries": [
    "reinvigoration:spider_charm_from_spiders"
  ]
}
```

I have two classes, AddItemModifier.java and ModLootModifiers.java, in src/main/java/com/soliid/reinvigoraion/loot.

AddItemModifier:

```
package com.soliid.reinvigoration.loot;

import com.google.common.base.Suppliers;
import com.mojang.serialization.Codec;
import com.mojang.serialization.codecs.RecordCodecBuilder;
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ObjectArrayList;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.level.storage.loot.LootContext;
import net.minecraft.world.level.storage.loot.predicates.LootItemCondition;
import net.minecraftforge.common.loot.IGlobalLootModifier;
import net.minecraftforge.common.loot.LootModifier;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class AddItemModifier extends LootModifier {
    public static final Supplier<Codec<AddItemModifier>> CODEC = Suppliers.memoize(()
            -> RecordCodecBuilder.create(inst -> codecStart(inst).and(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS.getCodec()
            .fieldOf("item").forGetter(m -> m.item)).apply(inst, AddItemModifier::new)));
    private final Item item;

    protected AddItemModifier(LootItemCondition[] conditionsIn, Item item) {
        super(conditionsIn);
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    protected ObjectArrayList<ItemStack> doApply(ObjectArrayList<ItemStack> generatedLoot, LootContext context) {
        generatedLoot.add(new ItemStack(item));
        return generatedLoot;
    }

    @Override
    public Codec<? extends IGlobalLootModifier> codec() {
        return CODEC.get();
    }
}
```

ModLootModifiers:

```
package com.soliid.reinvigoration.loot;

import com.mojang.serialization.Codec;
import com.soliid.reinvigoration.Reinvigoration;
import net.minecraftforge.common.loot.IGlobalLootModifier;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

public class ModLootModifiers  {
public static final DeferredRegister<Codec<? extends IGlobalLootModifier>> LOOT_MODIFIER_SERIALIZERS =
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.Keys.GLOBAL_LOOT_MODIFIER_SERIALIZERS, Reinvigoration.MODID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Codec<? extends IGlobalLootModifier>> ADD_ITEM =
            LOOT_MODIFIER_SERIALIZERS.register("add_item", AddItemModifier.CODEC);

    public static void register(IEventBus bus) {
        LOOT_MODIFIER_SERIALIZERS.register(bus);
    }
}
```

I registered LOOT_MODIFIER_SERIALIZERS in my main class here:

```
ModLootModifiers.register(modEventBus);
```

When I build & play the game, spiders do not drop spider charms. I am modding in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem. This is apparently broken in the latest Forge builds. There is a PR waiting to be merged that addresses the issue: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/pull/9554